# jquery: how to change span attribute within a list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

how can i change the attribute of the `<span>` within the selected/hovered list item? whenever i hover over one `<li>` item, only `background-color` seems to change but not the `<span>` text itself. i have multiple `<li>` items similar to the one below. if anything, i would have expected all `<span>` texts to change when hovering over the `<li>` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('li').hover(function() {
                $(this).attr('background-color', '#E07A5F');
                $('span').attr('font-size', '.2em');
            })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="../exercises/ready.html" target="_blank">exercises &nbsp;<span>ready</span></a></li>
```

Comment: `font-size` is not a span attribute.  It is a CSS property.  Try using `css()` instead of `attr()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `background-color` would only serve as an attribute but have no affect on your visual styles. You'd either have to toggle a CSS class or inject an inline style via [css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$(this).css('background-color', '#E07A5F');
```

The same applies for the span(s) you're planning on changing:

```
$('span').css('font-size', '.2em');
```

---

To change the span deriving from the hovered list item, you would do what @Taplar suggested below by using [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/), which would target all span descendants:

```
$(this).find('span').css('font-size', '.2em');
```

Comment: okay, got it thank you! so it changes all the `<span>`s when i hover any `<li>` item but how how about only changing the css of the `<span>` associated to the hovered `<li>` item? is there an easier way besides assigning different `id`s to all the spans?

Comment: `$('span', this).css(...)` or `$(this).find('span').css(...)`.  You should look into becoming familiar with contextual lookups.  @cr15py0n10n

Comment: Thank you @Taplar. Updated my answer based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

[`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) creates an attribute, so your code would result in this:

```
<li background-color="#E07A5F" font-size=".2em">
```

Where what you want is:

```
<li style="background-color:#E07A5F; font-size=.2em">
```

So you should be using the [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('li').hover(function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#E07A5F');
      $('span').css('font-size', '.2em');
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="../exercises/ready.html" target="_blank">exercises &nbsp;<span>ready</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

But, really, you should avoid inline styles as they generally result in duplication of code, don't scale well, and are hard to maintain. Instead, add or remove CSS classes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('li').hover(function() {
      $(this).addClass("bColor");
      $('span').addClass("size");
   });
})
```

```css
.bColor { background-color:#E07A5F; }
.size { font-size:.2em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="../exercises/ready.html" target="_blank">exercises &nbsp;<span>ready</span></a></li>
</ul>
```